# Consultar periodo entre 2 datas no sql

Tags: java, sql, mysqli, datetime, back-end

Estou com um banco de dados com registro.
preciso separar por data entre 2 periodos de inicio e fim.

data incio 22/09/15
data fim 22/10/16

ja tentei de 2 formas porem nem um puxa o resultado entre esse periodo.

```
SELECT vempresa,DATA,COUNT(bid) FROM bilhetes2 
WHERE vempresa LIKE '%UNIAO%' 
AND sentido = 'SAIDA' AND DATA BETWEEN '2022-09-15' AND '2022-10-16 23:59:59'  GROUP BY vempresa




SELECT vempresa,DATA,COUNT(bid) FROM bilhetes2 
WHERE vempresa LIKE '%UNIAO%' 
AND sentido = 'SAIDA' AND DATA > 
'2022-09-16 00:00:00'AND DATA < '2022-10-16 23:59:59'  GROUP BY vempresa
```

[IMAGEM DO RESULTADO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKuMz.png)

alguem me ajuda ?

Comment: As datas na imagem correspondem ao período informado...

Comment: não entendi a dúvida, com o @JéfBueno comentou, o resultado da query está de acordo com o que tem no `where`

Comment: então, e que eu preciso de todo os dias, durante esse periodo. 09/15, 09/16 09/17, 09/18 .... até o dia 10/16. entendeu ?

Comment: só por dia a data final na segunda data do between que vai retornar tudo. Por exemplo `DATA BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-12'` retorna todo o ano de 2022